# How to send an attachment with the Email in android?

Tags: android

Can any body share any code snippet in order to send an attachment with an email using android

native client.

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I found,

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{""});

i.setType("audio/amr");

i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + attachmentFilePath));

startActivity(i);
```